# Spring Boot: Is there a similar way to hold an XML resource of strings and reference them like in Androids framework?

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-boot, resources

Been browsing around and can't find a simple solution to this.

I have just started using Spring Boot and was trying to see if I can do something similar like in Android's `getResources().getString(R.string.mystring)`

I may have a changing list of say references to API docs, error code descriptions and many other "static strings" and would like to hold them in once place (i.e. in the res folder as an XML resource) for the same reasons it is recommended in Android (easy changes and easier for translation).

So far I have seen ways to say get an InputStream from a file in the resource folder...but that isn't quite what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a small subset of properties you can store the string in the application.properties use

Application.properties:

```
my.string.in.properties=test
```

Inside your bean:

```
@Value("${my.string.in.properties:my_default_value}")
String myString;
```

This will load the value "test" in myString. If the key is not present in the properties file, it'll load whatever you place after the `:`.

Comment: Thank you. This is a nice start but I would rather not clutter up my appliaction.properties config with say 100+ links and error code strings.
I would much prefer, if possible, a way to reference strings say from an XML document in the res folder like in Android.
If there does not seem to be an option for this, then yes, I will have to resort to maybe some terrible file parsing-> RAM ->JSON Object idea or the adding to properties.

Comment: Android generates the R class in a dynamic way using a preprocessor that listens the changes of the file and creates the 'giant' static class on compile time. That's why you can access it in a type-safe way.

Comment: @Jcov You really do not need to clutter your application.properties file. You can also have multiple files each representing one kind of data eg. error-code.properties.

Answer (score 2):

I am probably a little late to the party, but once possible solution is to still use a properties file and get the values using org.springframework.core.env.Environment, like this:

```
@Autowired
Environment env;
```

Then, you can get the value of an entry in the properties file like this:

```
env.getProperty("foo.bar");
```